# How to complete the following-Levi-Civita Symbol

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

> I am unable to simplify the following using Einstein notation:
>
> - $A_{ij}e_{ijk}e_{jkh}B_{gh}$
> - $e_{ijk}(u_{j,k}-u_{k,j})$
>
> where $e_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita Symbol.

My try:

2.$e_{ijk}(u_{jk}-u_{kj})=e_{ijk}u_{j,k}-e_{ijk}u_{k,j}$

I cant proceed after this.

1.$A_{ij}e_{ijk}e_{jkh}B_{gh}=e_{ijk}e_{jkh}A_{ij}B_{gh}=(\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}-\delta_{ik}\delta_{kh})A_{ij}B_{gh}$

I cant proceed after this.

Can someone kindly help please?

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get to?

Comment: The question says simplify the two using Einstein equaation

Comment: The problem is that the first expression does not follow Einstein's convention, since the symbol $j$ is present three times in the same factor

Comment: @caverac; so what should I do?How to proceed?